# After a deploy to EC2 sidekiq now reports SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, redis, sidekiq, celluloid

Application is Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.1.2.

Using sidekiq 3.2.6, redis 3.1.0, celluloid 0.15.2. The sidekiq implementation is as default as can be, with the exception of connecting to a remote redis queue (elastic cache).

When certain events are processed, we use sidekiq to queue up calls to an external API. The API is reachable through curl from the server our application is hosted on. All other functionality seems to still be performing as expected. This functionality has worked for weeks on the current server implementation/architecture.

After a successful deploy (with Capistrano, through Jenkins) to and EC2 instance, which is behind an elastic load balancer, and an auto-scaling group sidekiq will no longer connect(?) to elasticcache.

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152 in getaddrinfo
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152 in connect
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:211 in connect
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:304 in establish_connection
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:85 in block in connect
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:266 in with_reconnect
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:84 in connect
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:326 in ensure_connected
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:197 in block in process
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:279 in logging
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:196 in process
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102 in call
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:1315 in block in smembers
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:37 in block in synchronize
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211 in mon_synchronize
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:37 in synchronize
/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis.rb:1314 in smembers
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/api.rb:557 in block in cleanup
/gems/connection_pool-2.0.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:58 in with
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:72 in redis
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/api.rb:556 in cleanup
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/api.rb:549 in initialize
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:79 in new
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:79 in poll_interval
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:58 in block in poll
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15 in watchdog
/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/scheduled.rb:23 in poll
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25 in public_send
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25 in dispatch
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122 in dispatch
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322 in block in handle_message
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416 in block in task
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55 in block in initialize
/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13 in block in create
```

We have restarted sidekiq, restarted elastic cache, restarted the server, inspected the redis queue with redis-cli and seen nothing noteworthy.

As implied, we can connect to elastic cache using redis-cli, however, using `sidekiq/api`from the console, we get the same `SocketError`

Any ideas on how to remedy? The application is neigh unusable at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Take Sidekiq out of the situation.  Can you do a basic `require 'redis'; p Redis.new.info` in irb?

Comment: @MikePerham Interesting... When I do this I get the same SocketError. I did have to add the url for elastic cache as a param to `new`.

A quick google of redis socket error didn't yield any usable results, any idea?

Thanks Mike

Comment: Do you provide the URL to your redis instance in a `confg/sidekiq.rb` file? Typically, it would be in an ENV var. Is that ENV var set in your EC2 instance?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot its actually in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` for me, but yes its there. And as referenced above, it actually seems to be a redis issue, maybe? As I can't get to the elasticache instance even when taking sidekiq out of the equation.

Comment: Right, initializers. What I'm suggesting is to make sure you have the URL to your redis server correctly set in your EC2 instance e.g. when i connect to redis using redis-cli it will connect to the default `localhost:6379` but if your redis server is at a different URL you would have to give that to your client. Are you?

Comment: Yes, it is, sorry i wasnt clear before.

Answer (score 1):

Yay for embarrassing errors! There was a typo in the ENV var url. 10 hours later, between me and the devops, and it was a copy and paste issue.

Thanks